# JAVA - TLS SOCKET : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: java

I made a rdp protocol
so I used TLSv1.2 protocol.

but I had a problem with TLSv1.2

when I send packet to window server(RDP), do i make a certification?

or just use rdp certification?
[[image: TCPDump screenshot]

but finally they had a issue about alert(21)

I don't know what's wrong with it....
[image: TCPSocket Code]

and i enrolled window rdp certification in cacerts.

Comment: Can you say what Java distribnution/version this is and maybe try a different one? I am seeing "internaql_alerts" with Java 17 since a short time (however with a different endpoint)

Comment: BTW; You dont need the SSLContext if you dont use it and you might comment out the cipher-definition in order to see if it helps. But the `internal_error` alert is not really related to coding errors on your side.